# SetInterval is called more than one time

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am making a tetris game.

Here is the link for jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/e9q1mykt/1/

The problem/bug is that when playing the game `setInterval(move_tetris_part,interval_time);` is called more than one time, so the down speed is higher than normal.

I can't find why.

The problem is in keydown and keyup function.
A have a variable called job_completed which is true in the start of each button pressed and then would be false. Only if this variable is false the code executed.

```
document.onkeydown = function(event){
        can_move_left = true;
        can_move_right = true;
        can_rotate = true;

    switch(event.keyCode){
        case 37:
            //left;
            if(game_mode=="started" && job_completed){
            job_completed = false;
            //code there
            job_completed = true;
            }
    }
        case 39:
            //left;
            if(game_mode=="started" && job_completed){
            job_completed = false;
            //code there
            job_completed = true;
            }
case 40:
            //left;
            if(game_mode=="started" && job_completed){
            job_completed = false;
            //code there
            job_completed = true;
            }

       case 38:
            //left;
            if(game_mode=="started" && job_completed){
            job_completed = false;
            //code there
            job_completed = true;
            }
```

}

```
document.onkeyup = function(event){
    if(game_mode=="started"){
        switch(event.keyCode){
            case 37:
                //left
                if(job_completed){
                    game_mode = "started";
                    game_interval = setInterval(move_tetris_part,interval_time);
                    console.log("Set interval after pressing left arrow");
                }
                break;
            case 38:
                //up
                if(job_completed){
                    game_mode = "started";
                    part_can_move();
                    if(part_can_go_down){       
                        game_interval = setInterval(move_tetris_part,interval_time);
                        console.log("Set interval after pressing up arrow");
                    }else{
                        new_part();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 39:
                //right
                if(job_completed){
                    game_mode = "started";
                    game_interval = setInterval(move_tetris_part,interval_time);
                    console.log("Set interval after pressing right arrow");
                }
                //right
                break;
            case 40:
                //down
                if(job_completed){
                    if(game_mode == "started"){
                        if(interval_time==interval_time_speed){
                            clearInterval(game_interval);
                            console.log("Clear interval while pressing down arrow");
                            interval_time = interval_time_normal;
                            document.getElementById("interval_time").innerHTML = interval_time+" ms";
                            game_interval = setInterval(move_tetris_part,interval_time);
                            console.log("Set interval after pressing down arrow");
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 32:
                //space
                if(game_mode=="started" && job_completed){
                    job_completed = false;
                    console.log(job_completed);
                    clearInterval(game_interval);
                    console.log("Clear interval while pressing space arrow");
                    static_current_y = current_y;
                    for(var i=static_current_y;i<squares_y;i++){
                        current_y = i;
                        part_can_move();
                        if(part_can_go_down==false){
                            current_y = static_current_y;
                            delete_tetris_part();
                            current_y = i;
                            make_tetris_part(false);
                            clear_completed_lines();
                            score = score+((squares_y-static_current_y)*10);
                            document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
                            new_part();
                            job_completed = true;
                            console.log(job_completed);
                            return 1;
                        }
                    }
                    job_completed = true;
                    console.log(job_completed);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Please also, check the logs (console).

Thanks in advance,
Chris Pappas.

Comment: Please scale your issue down to a [mcve]. Nobody is going to sift through 5000 lines of code to help debug this. Also the relevant code should be in the question itself

Comment: What do you mean its called more than one time? That is the point of using `setInterval`

Comment: @IsaacVidrine my guess is Op is unintentionally creating multiple `setInterval`. But good question that needs clarification

Comment: @IsaacVidrine, calling `setInterval` more than once is not the same as calling the callback passed to `setInterval` more than once. ;-)

Comment: @trincot that's true!

Comment: So, how can i edit the question?

Comment: @ChrisP you should see an [`edit`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55521434/edit) link under the question.

Comment: Can you plz add specific  code that is creating problem ?

Comment: @MarkMeyer Ok, i see that! Question edited. If you think that i am not as cleared as possible please send a comment below.

Comment: @AzeemAslam i will try.

Comment: Question edited

Comment: @trincot good point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every `game_interval = setInterval(//...` should be preceded with `clearInterval`, I think in the `document.onkeyup` handler around line 1680 you neglected that.

Here's why: the interval shall keep ticking until it gets cleared (or the user closes window, or the world ends - one way or another, a forced stop). When you call one `setInterval` without clearing the one already ticking, the old one will keep going and the new one will start. So once every x milliseconds the first one will tick, and *independently* once every x milliseconds the second one will do as well. Which makes two ticks every x milliseconds. Add another, and it's 3 ticks, and so on, and so forth.

BTW, that script is huge and therefore hard to read. Concentrating on keeping it more DRY will help you locate bugs.

Comment: I have clearInterval in move_tetris_part() function in line 2602.
Have you checked this?

Comment: I will try to call clearInterval before setInterval in line 1680+.

Comment: Putting clearInterval before setInterval solved the problem.
I really don't know why. So please edit the answer to summarize the solution.
Thanks for the help.